# Looking for a way to forward SMS messages from a spesific numbers

Tags: sms, caller-id

I'm looking for a way to forward SMS messages received on my phone from a specific number.
The problem is that the number is a "service", meaning I don't see a number, I see a name like "AMEX", "Dominos", "MasterCard" ect...

Is there a way to get the number from these "services" ?
[By services I mean all these companies that send sms messages with a name instead of a number]

I have tried using [Sms Forwader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.yas.freeSmsForwarder) but it seems there is a bug and it forwards  messages from unwanted "services".

Is there any way to forward all the sms I get from (for example) "Dominos" to a specified number ?